# Check if values of splited string are in the string below

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a String colNotNull = "value1 value2 ". I need to split the String and check if it exists in the next String(queryConstr) . If it exists then i have to add "not null" else I have to add " "
This is how I should get the result(queryConstr)

```
  int valoareConstr = constrMax(max);
  String conNotNull = "value1 value2 ";
  String queryConstr = "ALTER TABLE persoane MODIFY value1 char(" + valoareConstr + ") + "not null",
                        MODIFY value2 char(" + valoareConstr + ") + "not null",
                        MODIFY value3 char(" + valoareConstr + ");";
```

What should i so it would work, any ideas?